# jquery remove all the divs except the one clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This code removes the div that is selected, i was trying to when i click in the button that is in the div,all the other would disapear, and the one that i clicked stayed, but i only can remove the one that i click, sry for my english and sry for being a beginner at jquery.

I have here a video to youtube to show you better what is my problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiUECo33-d0

```js
$('.product-removal button').click( function() {
       removeItem(this);
    });
    function removeItem(removeButton)
    {
        var productRow = $(removeButton).parent().parent();
            productRow.remove();
    }
```

```html
    
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Configurador</title>
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link href="css/ResponsiveAccordianMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="twd_container">
    <h1 style="margin:150px auto 30px auto; text-align:center">Configurar</h1>
    <!--Processador-->
    <div id="AL" class="expandContent">
        <h3 class="header">
            <div class="headerColumn1">Processador</div>
            <div class="headerColumn2 expand"><img src="img/plus.png" /></div>
            <div class="expandedContentClearFloat"></div>
        </h3>
        <div class="expandedContent">
            <div class="container">
                <ul id="orders">
                {% for item in processador %}
                    <div class="product-removal">
                    <li>
                <div class="row carousel-row" >
    
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 slide-row" id="container">
    
                        <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide slide-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
    
    
                            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img class="iconcomp" src="{{ item.img|e }}" alt="Image">
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide-content">
                            <h4>{{ item.marca|e }}</h4>
                            <p>
                                {{ item.descr|e }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide-cima" id="{{ item.id|e }}">
                          <span class="pull-right buttons">
                             <button class="btn2" id='remove' value='{{ item.id|e }}' onclick="rmv(this)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-undo"></i></button>
                          </span>
    
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide-footer" id="{{ item.id|e }}">
                          <span class="pull-right buttons">
                             <button name="" class="btn1" id='item' value='{{ item.id|e }}' ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                          </span>
                                <button class="remove-product">
                                    Remove
                                </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
                    </li>
                    </div>
    
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfloat"></div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- scripts-->

    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/ResponsiveAccordianMenu.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: " i only can remove the one that i click" why what happened? Move whatever extra info you added to the youtube video to your question here.

Comment: Beginner tips:  Use `$(button).closest(".slide-row")` to get the table row, rather than `.parent().parent()` - it's more flexible and allows you to move the button around in future (eg if you add additional wrapping or remove the .product-removal wrapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this this hides all div except one you click

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $('div').not(this).hide();
});
```

provide selector as per your's